# getting DeprecationWarning while using db.collection.count() function using pymongo in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, pymongo

**I'm using**

> `MongoDB shell version v4.4.0`
> **and**
> **`pymongo 3.10.0` version**

**when I use `any_db.any_collection.count()` or `any_db.any_collection.count({})` the warning show in console**

```
DeprecationWarning: count is deprecated. Use estimated_document_count or count_documents instead. Please note that $where must be replaced by $expr, $near must be replaced by $geoWithin with $center, and $nearSphere must be replaced by $geoWithin with $centerSphere
  print(f'Total Categories = {db.rank_list_category.count({})}')
```

**My code:**

```
import pandas as pd
from src.utils import get_full_path
from pymongo import MongoClient
from bson.objectid import ObjectId

client = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
db = client['techexpert']

print(f'Total Categories = {db["rank_list_category"].count({})}')
```

**Output:**

```
Total Categories = 5

    /home/mobin/PycharmProjects/IMDb/src/database/database_service_provider.py:17: DeprecationWarning: count is deprecated. Use estimated_document_count or count_documents instead. Please note that $where must be replaced by $expr, $near must be replaced by $geoWithin with $center, and $nearSphere must be replaced by $geoWithin with $centerSphere
  print(f'Total Categories = {db.rank_list_category.count({})}')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned [in the documentation](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.count)

> The count() method is deprecated and not supported in a transaction. Please use count_documents() or estimated_document_count() instead.

> When migrating from count() to count_documents() the following query operators must be replaced - $where, $near, $nearSphere

> Changed in version 3.7: Deprecated.

So use [count_documents](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.count_documents)

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this warning because `pymongo` is deprecating the `count` function, meaning that you should not use it anymore in new code.

Change your use from:

```
db.collection.count({})
```

to

```
db.collection.count_documents({})
```